# Apache2 not working with routes PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, routes, server, apache2

I am developing an app with PHP 7.0 and implementing routes with MVC. My root folder ('/') is the 'public' directory. When I access the address  'localhost' I am redirected to index.php with have the routes available. But when I try another url to access another route, like 'localhost/contact' the server doesn't find the entry and give this message:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /contact was not found on this server.
```

I am pretty sure that the problem in on my server config (apache2 on linux mint 18), because my friend's PC works normal. I'm using a .htaccess file too inside the public directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

It seems to me that the server does not run index.php and tries to access the path. How could I ever force the execution of index.php to see if there is a route to the url informed?

here follows my apache2 config files.

http://pastebin.com/2mgSjWWV

http://pastebin.com/yD4RpfK8

I'm still newbee and  I understand very little in server configuration. Please someone can give me a light? Thanks!

Comment: what `RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]` should do?

Comment: My teacher gave me that .htaccess. Looking in the web, the RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L] will apply the RewriteConds for any URL in my filesystem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
```

It matches EVERYTHING, and since it's tagged `[L]`, no other RewriteRules will be evaluated, so all rewriting stops here. That means a request for `example.com/foo` will match this rule, rewriting stops, and a literal `foo` file will be searched for in the file system - which doesn't exist.

And then, even if this one rule wasn't there, this next line

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

would also not work. ANY url would match it, but then strip off the relevant data, so a request for `example.com/foo` would be identical to a request for `example.com/index.php`. no query parameters would be passed in.

Your logic should be more like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?args=$1  [QSA,L]
```

which would do these sorts of translations:

```
example.com/foo      -> example.com/index.php?args=foo
example.com/bar?baz  -> example.com/index.php?args=bar&baz
```

Comment: Thanks, but I found the problem. My apache2 was not reading properly the .htaccess. My old .htacess was apparently working. Thanks for your time, you help me a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

After an exhaustive battery of tests, I found a solution. The htaccess file and code was fine. The problem was my server not reading the .htaccess. Editing the apache2.conf and seting 'AllowOverride All' on , finally works.

This page https://docs.bolt.cm/3.0/howto/making-sure-htaccess-works help me to solve that!